# How to get a list of imported function stored procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I'm trying to clean up horribly messy code with WAY too many stored procedures.

Before I modify or remove any sp I need to know what's using it.

Some of the sps are named in the code and easy to search for. Others I can only find if I go to Model Browser, expand Function Imports, and look at Properties of a particular function.

Is there a simple way to get a list of all Function Imports and their corresponding sp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured it out.

Accidentally opened text version of the edmx file and there's all the info.

Copied to excel to sort and extracted what I needed.